# Pandas resample.plot() not working because DatetimeIndexResampler

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I try to learn to use pandas, so I follow a tutorial.
However, during the tutorial, there is this:

```
bitcoin.loc['2019','Close'].resample('M').plot() plt.show()
```

And it returns an error :

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

But the man in the video gets a graph with different colors split by month, I don't understand why?
Maybe a wrong version of pandas or something else?

The link to the tutorial video: https://youtu.be/qHRLG5hsW9I?t=353

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

bitcoin = pd.read_csv('BTC-EUR.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=True) 

bitcoin.loc['2019','Close'].resample('M').plot()
plt.show()
```

Download the dataset:
BTC-EUR.csv = https://fr.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-EUR/history?p=BTC-EUR

Expected this:

[image: Expected result]

Got this:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By downloading the dataset, I had to look for the year '2023' (not '2019') by changing your code line as follows:

```
bitcoin.loc['2023','Close'].resample('M').plot()
```

By implementing this change, I get the expected results. Can you check if this solves your issue? Otherwise, the best is to check the versions of pandas that you have installed. The libraries I have installed and that work have the following versions:

```
numpy 1.23.5
matplotlib 3.5.1
pandas 1.5.3
```

Comment: Ok so it's because i have the pandas 2.0.1 version so it doesn't works. Thank you for yout help!